# Independent set of points in a square.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, statistics

Suppose I select points uniformly at random in $[0,1]^{2}$ and two points share an edge if their euclidean distance is less than $r$. Suppose I have $n$ points $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}$ selected in this way, how could I compute the probability that they are all independent given that $1<m<n$ of them are? One way would be to cover the $m$ points with circles of radius $r$ and calculate the probability that the remaining $n-m$ points form an independent set in a region outside that covered by the circles, but you would need to know how much area is covered in the first place which seems difficult to calculate.

Comment: can you solve the 1-dimensional case?

Comment: The approach i suggested still has the same problem, so i'd say i dont think so

Comment: Does reducing to the one dimensional case help? Any hints?

Comment: no special insight i'm afraid. my thought was just that it seems a very tricky problem, so reducing the complexity might generate a few ideas

Comment: Think about the boundary conditions. If the point $m_i$ is more than $r$ from both edges then it blocks a whole circle. If it isn't it blocks a smaller but calculable area.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a bit more?